# Assign involving both reducing & non-reducing operations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tidyverse

I'm an R/Tidyverse guy getting my feet wet in python/pandas and having trouble discerning if there is a way to do the following as elegantly in pandas as tidyverse:

```r
(
    dat
    %>% group_by(grp)
    %>% mutate(
        value = value/max(value)
    )
)
```

So, there's a grouped mutate that involves a non-reducing operation (division) that in turn involves the result of a reducing operation (max). I know the following is possible:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'grp': np.random.randint(0,5, 10), 'value': np.random.randn(10)}).sort_values('grp')

tmp = (
    df
    .groupby('grp')
    .agg('max')
)

(
    df
    .merge(tmp,on='grp')
    .assign(
        value = lambda x: x.value_x / x.value_y
    )
)
```

But I feel like there must be a way to avoid the creation of the temporary variable `tmp` to achieve this in one expression like I can achieve in tidyverse. Am I wrong?

Update: I'm marking @PaulS's answer as correct as it indeed addresses the question as posed. On using it something other than my minimal example, I realized there was further implicit behaviour in tidyverse I hadn't accounted for; specifically, that columns not involved in the series of specified operations are kept in the tidyverse case and dropped in @PaulS's answer. So here instead is an example & solution that more closely emulates tidyverse:

```py
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'grp': np.random.randint(0,5, 10) #to be used for grouping
        , 'time': np.random.normal(0,1,10) #extra column not involved in computation
        , 'value': np.random.randn(10) #to be used for calculations
    })
    .sort_values(['grp','time'])
    .reset_index()
)

#computing a grouped non-reduced-divided-by-reduced:
(
    df
    .groupby('grp', group_keys=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: (
            x.assign(
                value = (
                    x.value
                    / x.value.max()
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .drop(['index','level_0'],axis=1)
)
```

I also discovered that if I want to index into one column during the assignment, I have to tweak things a bit, for example:

```py
#this time the reduced compute involves getting the value at the time closest to zero:
(
    df
    .groupby('grp', group_keys=False)
    .apply(
        lambda x: (
            x.assign(
                value = (
                    x.value
                    / x.value.values[np.argmin(np.abs(x.time))] #note use of .values[]
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .drop(['index','level_0'],axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, a transform is a better fit, and should be more performant than apply:

```py
df.assign(value = df.value/df.groupby('grp').value.transform('max'))
   grp     value
1    0  1.000000
2    1 -0.290494
3    1  1.000000
4    1  0.214848
6    2  8.242604
7    2  1.000000
8    2  1.156246
0    3  0.655760
9    3  1.000000
5    4  1.000000
```

Comment: Yes, @sammywemmy, it is faster! +1

Comment: Ah, neat! It took me a second to notice the specific use of a grouped transform, which is how the reduced value is broadcast back to the original data size within each group.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
(df.groupby('grp')
 .apply(lambda g: g['value'].div(g['value'].max()))
 .droplevel(1)
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    grp      value
0    0   1.000000
1    1   1.000000
2    1   1.052922
3    2   1.000000
4    2   5.873499
5    3  10.009542
6    3   1.000000
7    4   1.000000
8    4  -0.842420
9    4   0.410153
```

Comment: Thanks! One aspect of your solution that mismatches what I'm familiar with in tidyverse is that at the end of the tidyverse operations, all initial columns persist whereas in your implementation only the columns that defined the groupby structure and the output of the apply are kept. I see that with pd.DataFrame.apply there's a result_type arg where `broadcast` would achieve my desired behaviour, but am I correct that one can't do `df.groupby('grp').apply(...,result_type='broadcast')`? Yields an error for me at least.

Comment: Welcome, @MikeLawrence! I am also coming from `tidyverse`. Which column would you like to persist? The `value` one? If I remember well, `mutate`, when uses the same `colname`, only updates such a column -- and it does not create a new one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my minimal example didn't contain extra columns as I belatedly realize would have been more realistic. Imagine just another column `var` that has just np.random.normal() content. I think I've worked it out though; if I do `.apply( lambda g: g.assign(...) )` that will keep all old columns and make a new one.

Comment: That is right, @MikeLawrence! Just an unrelated remark: The part `.droplevel(1)` is only needed because the index of your dataframe is not 0, 1, 2,... (because of the `sort` operation).

Comment: Note I updated my Q to include what I got to with your help plus a little bit extra I learned along the way. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeLawrence: I would suggest you to use `x.value[x.time.abs().idxmin()]` instead of `x.value.values[np.argmin(np.abs(x.time))]`: There is no need to use `numpy`, since one can accomplish that only with `pandas`.